# How to sort Marvel Cinematic Universe hero movies into a chronological order?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, chronology

If I wanted to watch all the MCU hero movies in chronological order, how would I need to watch them?

I am not referring to the *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* TV series (although it would be nice to fit that in, too).

Assuming S.H.I.E.L.D. (Fury, Coulson, etc.) is the connecting line in the story, is there any order?

Comment: Fortunately the MCU movies are released in chronological order. Yet I don't know how the individual episodes of *Agents of SHIELD* tie into that.

Comment: Are you also interested in non-MCU movies (for the uninitiated: *X-Men* and *Spider-Man*)? Yet, those have independent chronologies anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson no. Shield related only

Comment: Also answered on Science Fiction & Fantasy: [**Is there an official Marvel Cinematic Universe viewing order?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/is-there-an-official-marvel-cinematic-universe-viewing-order)

Comment: This is currently out-of-date. Find the current list [here](https://www.techradar.com/uk/how-to/how-to-watch-the-marvel-movies-in-order). PLEASE NOTE: this gets updated as new films / shows are released, so will always be up-to-date.

Comment: _Captain America: The First Avenger_ is set in the 1940s _and_ the 2010s, so it's a bit tricky.

Comment: The [currently accepted answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/21952/1006) is very outdated. It is missing a lot of MCU films and TV shows. It should be unaccepted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chronology order of Marvel Cinematic Universe (Own by Disney) is as follows :-

> **20th Century**
>
> - Captain America: The First Avenger
> - Agent Carter
>
>   - Now is Not the End
>   - Bridge and Tunnel
>   - Time and Tide
>   - The Blitzkrieg Button
>   - The Iron Ceiling
>   - A Sin to Err
>   - Snafu
>   - Valediction
> - Marvel One-Shot: Agent Carter
>
> **21st Century**
>
> - Iron Man
> - Iron Man 2
> - The Incredible Hulk
>
>   - Marvel One-Shot: A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to Thor's Hammer
> - Thor
>
>   - Marvel One-Shot: The Consultant
> - Captain America: The First Avenger (ending)
> - The Avengers
>
>   - Marvel One-Shot: Item 47
> - Iron Man 3
> - Marvel One-Shot: All Hail the King
> - Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season one)
>
>   - Pilot
>   - 0-8-4
>   - The Asset
>   - Eye-Spy
>   - Girl in the Flower Dress
>   - FZZT
>   - The Hub
> - Thor: The Dark World
> - Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season one)
>
>   - The Well
>   - Repairs
>   - The Bridge
>   - The Magical Place
>   - Seeds
>   - T.R.A.C.K.S.
>   - T.A.H.I.T.I.
>   - Yes Men
>   - End of the Beginning
> - Captain America: The Winter Soldier
> - Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season one)
>
>   - Turn, Turn, Turn
>   - One Door Closes (flashbacks)
>   - Providence
>   - The Only Light in the Darkness
>   - Nothing Personal
>   - Ragtag
>   - Beginning of the End
> - Guardians of the Galaxy
> - Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season two)
>
>   - Shadows
>   - Heavy is the Head
>   - Making Friends and Influencing People
>   - Face My Enemy
>   - A Hen in the Wolf House
>   - A Fractured House
>   - The Writing on the Wall
>   - The Things We Bury
>   - Ye Who Enter Here
>   - What They Become
>   - Aftershocks
>   - Who You Really Are
>   - One of Us
>   - Love in the Time of HYDRA
>   - One Door Closes
>   - Afterlife
>   - Melinda
>   - The Frenemy of My Enemy
>   - The Dirty Half Dozen
> - Avengers: Age of Ultron
> - Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (season two)
>
>   - Scars
>   - S.O.S. Part One
>   - S.O.S. Part Two

(Source:[marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline))

*Note:- [Marvel One-Shots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_One-Shots) are a series of direct-to-video short films produced by Marvel Studios. They are included as special features in the MCU films' Blu-ray and digital distribution releases.*

Comment: Ah, it seems I wasn't completely correct, of course *Captain America* is set way earlier. But Ok, if one interprets the WWII part as a flashback and the ending as the present, the release order fits again. And interesting to see how the TV-show fits in.

Comment: What a legendary answer. All we're missing now is if you REALLY wanted to view the footage in completely correct chronological order, to specify which scenes from each movie fit where. For example, backflashes in Thor and such.

Comment: @NICHOLASMARKAMOS that will be very tricky to maintain.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I wouldn't find it that hard. It would be the most absolute resource. Besides, some people in another comment have linked to pretty much this exact thing http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-199999#Timeline --- While it doesn't exactly tell you which scenes of each movie to watch, it does list the events in order. It wouldn't be too hard to then go and add which scene of the specified movie to watch at that point.

Comment: @NICHOLASMARKAMOS have you seen the 2020 plan...it will surely going to change too much in that.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes I have. I am aware of all of Marvel's publically released movie and TV plans.

Comment: This is currently out-of-date. Find the current list [here](https://www.techradar.com/uk/how-to/how-to-watch-the-marvel-movies-in-order). PLEASE NOTE: this gets updated as new films / shows are released, so will always be up-to-date.

Answer (score 6):

This is difficult because many of the movies/episodes overlap. Most notable is "Fury’s Big Week" which is the name for the week in which "The Incredible Hulk", "Iron Man 2", and "Thor" **all occurred simultaneously**.

There are scenes in "Thor: The Dark World" dating back to 2987 B.C. even though the majority occurred in 2012.

Similarly, "Captain America: The First Avenger" shows scenes from 1933 upto 2011 despite taking place mostly in 1943-1945

[**Here is the complete list of events with more detail than anyone needs**](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-199999#Timeline)

Comment: [Here's an interactive version](http://www.tiki-toki.com/timeline/entry/5395/A-Marvel-Cinematic-Universe-Timeline#vars!date=2217-04-11_10:37:46!) of the above, which is much more accessible.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Thats amazing

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested needs to exist in another comment I made. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

##### [This website](https://www.techradar.com/uk/how-to/how-to-watch-the-marvel-movies-in-order) gets updated whenever a new show / film is released, meaning it will always be up-to-date.

---

###### As of June 2022:

- Captain America: The First Avenger – takes place during WWII
- Captain Marvel – occurs in 1995
- Iron Man – takes place in 2008
- Iron Man 2 – takes place after Iron Man
- The Incredible Hulk – time unspecified, pre-Avengers
- Thor – events occur six months before Avengers
- The Avengers – takes place in 2012
- Iron Man 3 – takes place six months after The Avengers
- Thor: Dark World – post-Avengers, pre-Ultron
- Captain America: Winter Soldier – post-Avengers, pre-Ultron
- Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 1 – sometime in 2014
- Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 – set after Guardians
- Avengers: Age of Ultron – occurs in 2015
- Ant-Man – takes place in 2015
- Captain America: Civil War – post-Ultron, pre-Infinity War
- Black Widow – takes place right after Civil War
- Spider-Man: Homecoming – post-Civil War, pre-Infinity War
- Doctor Strange – takes place in 2016
- Black Panther – takes place in 2017
- Thor: Ragnarok – post-Ultron, pre-Infinity War
- Avengers: Infinity War – occurs in 2017
- Ant-Man and The Wasp – ambiguous, but fits nicely between Infinity War and - - Endgame (so around 2017)
- Avengers: Endgame – starts in 2018, ends in 2023
- Loki – spans the entire multiverse; best watched after Endgame
- What If...? – spans the entire multiverse; best watched after Endgame
- WandaVision – 2023
- The Falcon and the Winter Soldier – 2023
- Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings – 2023/2024
- Spider-Man: Far From Home – 2024
- Eternals – 2024
- She-Hulk: Attorney at Law – unspecified; likely 2024
- Moon Knight – unspecified; likely 2024
- Spider-Man: No Way Home – late 2024
- Hawkeye – late 2024
- Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness – 2025
- Ms Marvel – 2025
- Thor: Love and Thunder – unspecified; likely 2025
- Werewolf by Night – unspecified, likely 2025

Comment: The list doesn't make much sense to me. That site is flooded with ads, and I don't really like it, personally, so it's no wonder. If you can sort it out yourself, using official references, and come with actual table, that would be great. (But time consuming.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar if you scroll down, or use the subtitles, you can find the list above.

Answer (score 1):

Marvel.com has updated its *official*, chronological list of MCU movies and TV shows as of February 8, 2024. Here it is:

[image: MCU Complete Timeline]

##### MCU Complete Timeline

- Captain America: The First Avenger
- Marvel Studios One Shot: Agent Carter
- Captain Marvel
- Iron Man
- Iron Man 2
- The Incredible Hulk
- Marvel Studios One Shot: A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to Thor’s Hammer
- Thor
- Marvel Studios One Shot: The Consultant
- Avengers
- Marvel Studios One Shot: Item 47
- Thor: The Dark World
- Iron Man 3
- Marvel Studios One Shot: All Hail the King
- Captain America: The Winter Soldier
- Guardians of the Galaxy
- Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2
- I Am Groot S1
- I Am Groot S2
- Daredevil S1
- Jessica Jones S1
- Age of Ultron
- Ant-Man
- Daredevil S2
- Luke Cage S1
- Iron Fist S1
- The Defenders
- Civil War
- Black Widow
- Black Panther
- Spider-Man: Homecoming
- Punisher S1
- Doctor Strange
- Jessica Jones S2
- Luke Cage S2
- Iron Fist S2
- Daredevil S3
- Thor: Ragnarok
- Punisher S2
- Jessica Jones S3
- Ant-Man and the Wasp
- Infinity War
- Avengers Endgame
- Loki S1
- What If…? S1
- WandaVision
- Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings
- The Falcon and the Winter Soldier
- Spider-Man: Far From Home
- Eternals
- Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness
- Hawkeye
- Moon Knight
- Black Panther: Wakanda Forever
- Echo
- She-Hulk: Attorney at Law
- Ms. Marvel
- Thor: Love and Thunder
- Werewolf By Night
- The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special
- Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania
- Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3
- Secret Invasion
- The Marvels
- Loki S2
- What If…? S2

Source: https://www.marvel.com/articles/movies/mcu-timeline-order-disney-plus

If you’re curious about how different events fit into this timeline, you can read the book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios%27_The_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_An_Official_Timeline)*, which gives you more details and insights.

> I am not referring to the *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* TV series (although it would be nice to fit that in, too).

Unfortunately, both the Marvel.com list and the official timeline book do not include anything from *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, which suggests that it happens in a different timeline from the main MCU universe (616).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the producers/movie studio (correctly) set things up so that if you watched the movies as they were released, you'd be watching them in the 'correct' order.

Hence, the Wikipedia list by order of US release date is probably what you want to use.

In cases where the release dates were close to each other, it probably doesn't matter too much which you watch first. E.g. from what I recall, Iron Man (released in May 2008) and Incredible Hulk (June 2008) did not seem to have any references to each other, so it is probably 'no big deal' to watch either one before the other.

[image]

> [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Films)

Comment: He is searching for chronological order not releasing order.